# Accesstoken facebook not active?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, zend-framework, authentication

I am using facebook to authenticate and lend them certain rights.
Iam using the Zend Framework and have this code in my bootstrap class within the function

```
initFacebook(){

$db = Application_Model_DB::create();
  $db->setTable('users');

  Zend_Session::start();
  $facebookuser = new Zend_Session_Namespace('facebookUser');


  include('../library/Facebook/facebook.php');


   $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => '282270168507838',
        'secret' => '*cencor*',
      ));
   $accesstoken = $facebook->getAccessToken();

   try {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?accesstoken='.$accesstoken);
         $user = $facebook->getUser();
         $fbname = $user_profile['name'];

         $result = $db->fetchAllAsArray('fbid = "'.$user.'"');

         if (count($result) == 0) {
             $db->save(array('fbid'=>$user,'status'=>'standard','name'=>$fbname));
         }
         else {
              $facebookuser->status = $result[0]['status'];
              $facebookuser->fbname= $result[0]['name'];
              $facebookuser->fbuser = $result[0]['fbid'];


         }


      } catch (Exception $e) {
         $user = 0;
         $facebookuser->error = $accesstoken;
         $facebookuser->unsetAll();

   }
}
```

But this works for only a about 10 minutes to a few hours.

on http://www.nicomollema.nl/ i have a demo, i use de PHP SDK to do the serverside coding, and i use de javascript sdk to generate the login/logout button.

When i check the error it gives me is this: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

but as you can see i do : $accesstoken = $facebook->getAccessToken(); to get the accesstoken, so how can it be invalid?

Answer (score 0):

I made a capital mistake: I used a different APPID in the JavaScript SDK from the one in the PHP SDK. These, of course, have to be the same.